SwiftUI Error of satisfying constrains when clicking on textfield
When I try to create a simple login/signup page and click on the text field, it first lags and says Can't find or decode rasons. Then it times out and says unable to simulatiously satify constraints.  I havn't added anything that should be really interfiering with constraints(even made a new project to make sure).
This is the code I've tried for the basic implementation:
ContentView.swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var email: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                TextField("Email", text: $email)
                    
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                    .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    
                
                SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                    
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                    .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}




Cannot reproduce your issue. I noticed, you have a blank line
between the TextField and the .frame(width: 300, height: 50),
is this because you have something else there, like large .font

@workingdogsupportUkraine I just did that to have the spacing and sizing of the textfield. I have a complete blank project and that's the only code I have in it.

What system are you using and targetting? I’m on,
MacOS 14.5, Xcode 16-beta, target iOS-17.5, tested on real ios devices and simulators and MacCatalyst.

@workingdogsupportUkraine im on MacOS sequoia also using xcode 16 beta targted to ios 17.5. Though to make sure it wasnt cause of beta, I had my friend who was running mac os sonoma with xcode 15.4 also try it and same issue.

step 1: A SwiftUI project contains one and only one entry point. So search for the app swift file , it should look like the below given set of codes, search for key words like "@main" , struct [AppName]App: App etc to find the file.
import SwiftUI

@main
struct [ProjectName]App: App {
  
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView{
               ContentView()  
             }
          }
      }
  }

Step 2:- I removed the navigation stack from ContentView() and placed it in the top hierarchy.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var email: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                TextField("Email", text: $email)
                    
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                    .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    
                
                SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                    
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                    .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

Try this it should work.

No, that didn't work. Still getting the same issue.

@SheehanMunim try replacing  NavigationStack  with NavigationView .

I would have used NavigationView, though it was fully deprecated recently https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationview
